# Comparing strings after strtok

Tags: c++, strtok

Im tring to compare strings after strtok but i seem to be getting false instead of a true

is there anything else i need to do if im using strtok?

```
char file[] = "temp.txt";
ifstream getfile;
getfile.open(file,ios::in);
if(getfile.is_open())
{
        char data[256];
    char *line;
    const char * test = "init";

    //loop till end of file                   
    while(!getfile.eof())
    {
        //get data and store to variable data
            getfile.getline(data,256,'\n');

        line = strtok(data," ");
        while(line != NULL)
        {
            cout << "Comparing " << line << " with " << test <<endl;
            //This is suppose to print but it dosent
            if(line == test)
                cout << line << endl;

            line = strtok(NULL," ");
        }

    }
}
```

output :

```
 comparing init with init
```

wanted output:

```
 comparing init with init
 init
```

thanks! :D

===========================

changed to the following and it worked! :)

```
if(strcmp(line,test)==0)
```

Comment: There is a lot to fix in that code. You should try and write it using C++. Seriously ask the question on how to tokenize a file in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing pointers not content. Look into strcmp or wrap the C-strings in a std::string.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing pointers (the addresses of the strings).  They will always be different.  Use `strcmp()` to compare the strings themselves.